# XML Parsing with DOMXpath showing all child elements

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, xpath

I have this part of an auto-convert class which walks automatically through a XML file:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $entries = $xpath->evaluate($this->item,$doc);
    $csv = array();
    $i = 1;

    foreach($entries as $el) {
        foreach($el->childNodes as $node) {

            if(!empty($map)) {

                // not a real node OR not in the mapped array, and only mapped fields should be output
                if($node->nodeType==3 or (!in_array($node->nodeName,$map) and $this->selectedFields)) continue;

                if(!in_array($node->nodeName,$map)) {

                    $csv[0][$node->nodeName]=$node->nodeName;
                    $csv[1][$node->nodeName]=$node->nodeName;
                    $csv[$i][$node->nodeName] = $node->textContent;    

                } else {

                    $csv[0][$node->nodeName]=$remap[$node->nodeName];
                    $csv[$i][$remap[$node->nodeName]] = $node->textContent;    

                }
            } else {

                if($node->nodeType==3) continue;
                $csv[0][$node->nodeName]=$node->nodeName;
                $csv[1][$node->nodeName]=$node->nodeName;
                $csv[$i][$node->nodeName] = $node->textContent;    
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

One item of the XML tree looks like this:

```
<cac:Item>
    <cbc:Description>BREMSBELAG GALFER ORGAN. FD171-G1054 (KBA)</cbc:Description>
    <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        <cac:ID>04303400</cac:ID>
    </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
    <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
        <cac:ID identificationSchemeID="EAN/UCC-13">8400160001718</cac:ID>
    </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
    <cac:ManufacturersItemIdentification>
        <cac:ID>FD171-G1054</cac:ID>
        <cac:IssuerParty>
           <cac:PartyName>
               <cbc:Name>Galfer</cbc:Name>
           </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:IssuerParty>
     </cac:ManufacturersItemIdentification>
     <cac:BasePrice>
         <cbc:PriceAmount amountCurrencyID="EUR">5.95</cbc:PriceAmount>
         <cbc:BaseQuantity quantityUnitCode="EA">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
      </cac:BasePrice>
      <cac:RecommendedRetailPrice>
         <cbc:PriceAmount amountCurrencyID="EUR">10.9</cbc:PriceAmount>
         <cbc:BaseQuantity quantityUnitCode="EA">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
      </cac:RecommendedRetailPrice>
</cac:Item>
```

The output is almost perfect:

> Beschreibung,Hartje-ID,EAN,"Hersteller ID",Einkaufspreis,Verkaufspreis,Packemenge,Artikelinformation "BREMSBELAG GALFER ORGAN. FD171-G1054 (KBA)"," 04303400 "," 8400160001718 "," FD171-G1054 Galfer "," 5.95 1 "," 10.9 1 "

But you can see that RecommandedRetailPrice (Verkaufspreis) is mixed from its child nodes but I need them seperatly with their own headers.

Hope you have an idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto convert is a really bad idea, you will loose the structure information of the DOM (and the namespaces) and you will loose the possibility to use Xpath. The XML example is broken, too. The namespace definitions (xmlns:cac="" and xmlns:cbc="") are missing.

A DOM is a data source, you use expressions (think sql statement) to define which part of the data source you need. Be explicit:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($xmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// register namespaces - check the source document for the correct namespace strings
$xpath->registerNamespace('cac', 'urn:cac');
$xpath->registerNamespace('cbc', 'urn:cbc');

// define xpath expressions for the columns
$columns = [
  'Beschreibung' => 'string(cbc:Description)',
  'Hartje-ID' => 'string(cac:SellersItemIdentification/cac:ID)',
  'EAN' => 'string(cac:StandardItemIdentification/cac:ID)',
  'Hersteller ID' => 'string(cac:ManufacturersItemIdentification/cac:ID)',
  'Einkaufspreis' => 'number(cac:BasePrice/cbc:PriceAmount)',
  'Verkaufspreis' => 'number(cac:RecommendedRetailPrice/cbc:PriceAmount)',
  'Packemenge' => 'number(cac:BasePrice/cbc:BaseQuantity)'
];

// open a file stream for the standard output
$csvStream = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');

// write the columns names
fputcsv($csvStream , array_keys($columns));

//iterate all items
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//cac:Item') as $item) {
  // a row for an item
  $row = [];
  foreach ($columns as $expression) {
    // use the expression to fetch data for the columns and add it
    $row[] = $xpath->evaluate($expression, $item);
  }
  // write to the output stream
  fputcsv($csvStream, $row);
}
```

Output:

```
Beschreibung,Hartje-ID,EAN,"Hersteller ID",Einkaufspreis,Verkaufspreis,Packemenge
"BREMSBELAG GALFER ORGAN. FD171-G1054 (KBA)",04303400,8400160001718,FD171-G1054,5.95,10.9,1
```